# How to call one method in an ES6 class from another one?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

if I have a javascript ES6 class like this:

```
import $ from "jquery"; 

export class test {

  constructor() {
    this.es6 = 'yay';
  }

  writeLine(text){
    console.log(text);
  }

  getTestData(){
    writeLine('writeLine call'); // <-- can not call writeLine ??
    $.get('/test', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.data);
        this.es6 = data.data;
        debugger
        writeLine(data.data);
    });
 }
}
```

From another file I import the class and call getTestData

```
System.import('app/classDefinition')
.then(function(classDefinitionModul) {
   var test = new classDefinitionModul.test();
   console.log(test.es6);
   test.getTestData();
})
```

How can I call the method `writeLine`??

Comment: You want `this.writeLine`

Comment: for the first call it works but not for the second in the get

Comment: Of course, because `this` is not what you think it is. You have to either cache it, bind it, or use fat arrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with es6.
In the ajax callback, `this` doesn't refer to the object anymore.

```
getTestData () {

    // this isn't java (see what I did there)
    this.writeLine('writeLine call');

    var _this = this;
    $.get('/test', function (resp) {
        _this.writeLine(resp.data);
    });

    // or
    $.get('/test', function (resp) {
        this.writeLine(resp.data);
    }.bind(this));

    // or
    $.get('/test', resp => this.writeLine(resp.data))
}
```

Comment: Or `$.get('/test', data => this.writeLine(data.data))`

Comment: @elclanrs I'm not up to date with this witchcraft.

Comment: `=>` is like `function(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and does not address: "writeLine('writeLine call'); // <-- can not call writeLine ??"

Comment: One of my realizations from this is that you need to be in the scope of 'this' when you use =>, meaning call your methods using => from the constructor. This way they retain lexical scope to their peer methods. You can't just throw => into a method that's already lost the objects 'this'.