# Why can I not call this method from another method in the same class?

Tags: javascript

In the code below I can't figure out how to call the parseData(data) method from inside the handler(sock) method.

I have tried it in all of the ways from this other question:  [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820876/how-to-call-one-method-in-an-es6-class-from-another-one)

```js
"use strict";
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

class Sorter {
    constructor(sorter) {
        this.sorter = sorter;
        console.log(sorter.name + ' Port: ' + sorter.port + ' running!');
        this.initialize();
    }

    initialize() {
        net.createServer(this.handler).listen(this.sorter.port, HOST);
    }

    handler(sock) {
        sock.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.localPort + ':   ' + data);

            parseData(data);
            // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
            //sock.write('Hello there'); //response
        });

        // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
        sock.on('close', function(data) {
            console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
        });
    }

    parseData(data) {
        // find out if I have a carton with the data recvd
        console.log('looking for container: ' + data + ' ...');
        console.dir(this.findByContainer(data));
    }

    findByContainer(container) {
        return GLOBAL.CARTONS.filter(function( obj ) {
            return +obj.container === +container;
        })[0];
    }
}

module.exports = Sorter;
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be called by its namespace?

sorter.parseData(data)

Comment: Neither of those work, it seems somehow this is a Socket, not the class.

Comment: How are you calling this? What's the exact error message?

Comment: You are actually calling it from `sock.on`.  Maybe you can define the `function(data)` function outside the `sock.on` call or pass a reference to `this`?

Comment: In some places, you reference local function as `this.initialize` and others as `parseData`, you should be more consistent so we're not trying to guess why they're different

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.parseData(data);`.
 *this* has to be referenced, due the class instanciation.
See other calls inside the method.

Comment: But in this specific case, `this.parseData` is inside of a callback to the socket's `data` event – `sock.on` – and so `this` wouldn't refer to the correct thing. There needs to be some kind of scope binding before that will work.

Answer (score 0):

`parseData` is not in scope. You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) functions so that they are in scope when you call them from a different scope.

You have the right idea when you call `this.initialize()`; it's not a global function, so you need to refer to `this`. You need to do the same for `parseData`.

However, because you are calling `parseData` from a callback, `this` will not be what you expect it to be. You need to bind the callback or save a reference to `this` outside of the callback. I prefer the former, but it's up to you.

*Using `bind`:*

```
sock.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.localPort + ':   ' + data);

    this.parseData(data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
    //sock.write('Hello there'); //response
}.bind(this));
```

---

*Using a saved reference to `this`:*

```
var _this = this;
sock.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.localPort + ':   ' + data);

    _this.parseData(data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
    //sock.write('Hello there'); //response
});
```

You could also use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the callback. Scope is automatically maintained for arrow functions, but you still need to reference `this` to call `parseData`.

*Using an arrow function:*

```
sock.on('data', data => {
    console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.localPort + ':   ' + data);

    this.parseData(data);
    // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
    //sock.write('Hello there'); //response
});
```

Comment: I have tried all of these, none work. It seems somehow 'this' is a Socket object. Not sure how that could be.

Comment: The code blocks are a little confusing, can you label them so it is clear that the first one is a copy of the original problem and the other two are solutions?

Comment: @Trisped his code blocks are different options for solving the issue, but none of them work for some reason on this particular code.

Comment: So I figured out if I move the parseData and findByContainer methods out of the class it works.

Comment: @ShaneGrant Can you update your question and add the final code you went with?  Or you could add an answer with the solution you used.

Comment: I only copied a small part of the original code; this wasn't supposed to be a copy-and-paste replacement.

I wonder if whatever is calling `this.handler` is doing its own binding, and that's why `this` is a Socket object inside `handler`?

Comment: Moving the functions to a "global" scope kind of defeats the purpose of making them instance-level functions, but whatever works for you is good. I'm keeping this answer because it should apply more broadly to instances where scope is not correct.

Comment: When you say you tried all of these, what did you actually try? The snippets I provided were just part of the first few lines of `handler`. Can you add to your question what code you tried and what code you ended up with?